# React - audio element not playing - "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a drum machine using React but I can't get my audio clips to play via the onClick. I've browsed similar questions but none of them did it for me.

My Github: [drum-machine](https://github.com/Antonio-Riccelli/react-drum-machine)

My code below. I originally had the audio clips in a separate Libs folder, but I've copied and pasted them in the specific component folder (DrumMachine) to see if the issue was related to the path, but it still doesn't work.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPGUT.png)

Code:

DrumMachine component

```
 import React from 'react';
    import './index.css';
    import DrumPad from '../DrumPad/index';
    
    export default function DrumMachine(props) {
        const keys = ["Q", "W", "E", "A", "S", "D", "Z", "X", "C"];
        const elements = ["crash1", "crash2", "hatClosed1", "hatClosed2", "hatOpen1", "hatOpen2", "kick", "snare", "tambourine"];
        const audioClips = ["./Crash_1.wav", "./Crash_2.wav", "./Hat_Closed_1.wav", "./Hat_Closed_2.wav", "./Hat_Open_1.wav", "./Hat_Open_2.wav", "./Kick.wav", "./Snare_2.wav", "./Tambourine.wav"];
    
         async function handleClick(e) {
            const sound = await  new Audio (e);
            await sound.play();
        }
    
        return (
            <section id="drum-machine">
                <section id="display">
                    {keys.map((element, index) => {
                        console.log(audioClips[index]);
                        return (
        <DrumPad className="drum-pad" id={elements[index]} key={index} text={element} onClick={() => handleClick(audioClips[index])}>
                                <audio type="audio/WAV" src={audioClips[index]} className="clip" id={element}></audio>
                            </DrumPad>
                        )
                    })}
                </section>
            </section>
        )
    }
```

DrumPad component

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css'

export default function DrumPad(props){
const className = props.className;
const id = props.id;
const text = props.text;
const handleClick = props.onClick

return (
    <section >
    <button id={id} className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
        {text}
        {props.children}
        </button>
     
    </section>
)
}
```

Appreciate your help.